# jQuery Validation plugin and custom error messages in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I'm trying to get client-side validation working in ASP/NET MVC4 but without the server-side attributes and data annotations. I want to do it strictly using the jQuery Validation plugin in my view. Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="mainForm" method="post" action="/Department/Save">

@Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the errors")
<label>Department Name:</label><input type="text" id="DepartmentName" name="DepartmentName"/>  
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
<br />    
<label>Department Name Fr:</label><input type="text" id="DepartmentNameFr" name="DepartmentNameFr"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" />
```

Here is my jQuery script:

```
          $("#formWeek").validate({
          highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
              $(element).add($(element).parent()).addClass("input-validation-error");
          },
          unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
              $(element).add($(element).parent()).removeClass("input-validation-error");
          }
      });          

      $('#DateRangeCriteriaWeek').rules('add', {
          required: true,
          regex:"(201[3-9]|20[2-9][0-9])-(0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-3])", 
          messages: {
              required: "Date Range Criteria is required.",
              regex: "Date Range Criteria format is invalid."
          }
      });
```

At the beginning, I wasn't even getting any error messages popping up, I was just getting red textboxes when I left the inputs blank (when I clicked the submit button). I originally thought that jQuery would display the error messages automatically, but it didn't. However, when I added the Html.ValidationSummary helper, the error messages suddenly appeared.

Then I noticed that the error messages were the default messages, not the custom ones that I defined above. I figured out that in order to display custom messages, I had to use the rules method as shown above. But now the messages are not disappearing when the user corrects the errors.

Here is the rendered HTML:

```
<form id="formWeek" method="post" data-ajax-update="#ProductsDivWeek" data-ajax-success="process('Week')" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax="true" action="/Dashboard/Products?Length=9" novalidate="novalidate">
<div>
    <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
        <ul>
        <li style="display:none"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Date : </td>
        <td>
            <input id="DateRangeFilterWeek" type="hidden" value="FiscalWeek" name="DateRangeFilter">
            <span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span>
            <input id="DateRangeCriteriaWeek" class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" value="21/09/2013" name="DateRangeCriteria" data-val-required="Date Range Criteria is required." data-val="true" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input id="btnApplyWeek" type="submit" title="Apply" value="Apply" name="btnApply">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So you are only using the jQuery Validate plugin by itself, no `unobtrusive` right?  Also show the _rendered_ HTML markup of the form.

Comment: That is my goal, yes. Should I remove any reference to the unobtrusive javascript files?

Comment: AFAIK, yes.  I'm not an ASP expert but I know about how to get this plugin working.  Show the _rendered_ HTML markup of the form and I'll show you how to properly apply this plugin.

Comment: I think I figured our how to display the custom error messages, I used the rules method (my modified jQuery code is shown above). But the custom error message does not disappear when the user fixes the errors. I also show the rendered form HTML above. I don't want to remove the unobtrusive files from the project because it is used elsewhere in the application.

Comment: I know very little about how ASP activates, includes or applies `unobtrusive` validation to the form, but if you're going to keep it, make absolutely sure it's not being applied where you don't want it.... i.e. remove all unnecessary attributes from any/all form/input tags.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method or rule called `regex` within the jQuery Validate plugin.  You'll have to create this custom method using the built-in `.addMethod()` method.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("regex", function (value, element, param) {
    var regex = new RegExp(param);
    return regex.test(value);
}, "");


$('#DateRangeCriteriaWeek').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    regex: "^(201[3-9]|20[2-9][0-9])-(0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-3])",
    messages: {
        required: "Date Range Criteria is required.",
        regex: "Date Range Criteria format is invalid."
    }
});
```

See documentation for `addMethod`:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/jrLSF/

Also, since you're not using `unobtrusive.validate.js`...

1)  You've defined your rules and messages elsewhere, so AFAIK, you do not need any of the `data-val-` attributes.

2)  Remove the `data-ajax-` attributes from `<form>` tag and put any `.ajax()` in the `submitHandler` function.

```
submitHandler: function () {
    // ajax goes here;
    return false;
}
```